# How to list jenkins slaves of selected projects

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-agent

For example, I want to list slaves that are defined in "Foo" jobs: Project_Foo1, Project_Foo2 etc...

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /Foo/
}
```

I can list projects name, but how to get the slave names?

Comment: Do you mean that you restrict where projects can be run by setting Label Expression, and you want to get possible slaves where they could be run?

Comment: @arasio Yes ( I didnt use labels - each job has dedicated slave). Now I want to see slaves used in those projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some groovy way

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll{ job -> 
  job.name =~ /test/ && job.getAssignedLabel() != null 
}.collect { job ->
      "${job.name}: ${job.getAssignedLabel().getNodes().collect({it.getNodeName()==""?"master":it.getNodeName()}).join(',')}\n" 
}.each { slaves ->
    println slaves
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the FindAll closure, your `job` variable should hold a `TopLevelItem` instance (per the [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItems())).

So all you should have to do is `job.allJobs` to get a collection of children jobs ([javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Item.html#getAllJobs())) and then its `getName()` method.

In the end, something like

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
  job.name =~ /Foo/
}
def childrenJobNames = matchedJobs.allJobs*.name
```

should work, but I don't have a Jenkins instance to test it.

Comment: I already printing projects names, I need to get slaves names defined in those projects.

Comment: Is the configured slave listed in `matchedJobs.allJobs*.properties` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a label expression of a project by `getAssignedLabel()`.
And get nodes which meet the label expression by `getNodes()` of Label.

```
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
  if(job.name =~ /Foo/) {
    for(Node node : job.getAssignedLabel().getNodes()) {
      println node.getNodeName()
    }
  }
}
```

`getNodeName()` returns empty string if it's master.

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#getAssignedLabel()
http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Label.html#getNodes()
http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Node.html#getNodeName()